# Connecting Firebase to an React Native App that's using Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am currently trying to connect Firebase to my React Native app that uses Expo. Im currently using this guide: https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-firebase/?fbclid=IwAR0c7g8a-005utr_ROomb_k3ptlAHel3kq004AtFbNkV9iWREeapzR0Dabg and it lead me to the github "Firebase JS SDK". I downloaded the whole github repo (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) and like tried following the instructions on the github such as downloading node, yarn, and java but I am confused on what to do next with the downloaded repo. I have tried running the command "npm install" to try and install the dependencies but I get this error:

```
npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...cMP/3jKIr36/huSPHVVgD'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ban-Jian\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-19T23_15_25_175Z-debug.log
```

And when I run the command: "yarn build" I get this error:

```
lerna ERR! yarn run build exited 2 in '@firebase/firestore'
lerna ERR! yarn run build stdout:
$ tsc -m es2015 --moduleResolution node scripts/*.ts
error TS6053: File 'scripts/*.ts' not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

lerna ERR! yarn run build stderr:
error Command failed with exit code 2.

lerna ERR! yarn run build exited 2 in '@firebase/firestore'
lerna WARN complete Waiting for 4 child processes to exit. CTRL-C to exit immediately.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I guess my question is: How do I properly set up the SDK I downloaded from the github?